# Oracle Sql Developer (Select Count) Twoc olumns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to make a query that has the Total number of customers by country and city

country and city are columns that are inside the customer table

On my own I have managed to get the total number of customers per city like this:

```
SELECT city, COUNT (*)
FROM employees
GROUP BY city
ORDER BY city
```

But how do I get it together with the country?
looking for information I think it should be something like this and ordered from largest to smallest

| Country | City | TOTAL_CUSTOMERS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| USA | Kirkland | 3 |
| USA | London | 2 |
| UK | Redmond | 2 |
| UK | Seattle | 1 |
| UK | Tacoma | 1 |

What we have been told is to say Total number of customers by country and city.

Comment: I don't get a message :(

Comment: you write you have two tables, but in see only a result set, so make please a [mre]

Comment: I've added an image, would that work for you?
  I'm pretty new, sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: images are not allowed see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: I didn't know, so I'll remove the image.
But to summarize within the customer table I have two columns, one with cities and the other with countries.

I have been asked to say the total number of customers by country and city.
I know how to do it independently, but not how to get the example I gave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply add country to the column list and group by list:

```
SELECT country,city, COUNT(*)
FROM employees
GROUP BY country,city
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: You just missed one small detail, '_ordered from largest to smallest_'.

Comment: order by changed